# fabric waits for input in hosts of Amazon Linux and does not proceed

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, fabric

I am trying to use a deploy tool, fabric.
I succeeded to execute fab command for hosts of CentOS and Ubuntu EC2 instance.
But, I faild to execute for hosts of Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

The command I excecuted is following:

```
$ fab -f fab_test.py getHostname
```

fab_test.py:

```
$ cat fab_test.py
from fabric.api import run, env

env.hosts = ["*** host ip addr ***"]
env.user = "ec2-user" # clduser for CentOS and ubuntu for UbuntuOS
env.port = "*** port number ***"
env.key_filename = "/path/to/clduser.pem"

def getHostname():
    run("hostname")
```

succeeded result:

```
[*** host ip addr ***] Executing task 'getHostname'
[*** host ip addr ***] run: hostname
[*** host ip addr ***] out: host-name
[*** host ip addr ***] out:


Done.
```

failed result:

```
[*** host ip addr ***] Executing task 'getHostname'
[*** host ip addr ***] run: hostname
[*** host ip addr ***] out: [ec2-user@host-name ~]$
```

"failed" means fabric wait for input and does not proceed "hostname" command.
When I input some command to prompt, the command is executed in remote host correctly.
So I think establishing ssh connection is OK.
The instances of Amazon Linux are just created and nothing are installed.
guest machine is also EC2 instance of Amazon Linux.

Anyone can solve this problem?
I could not find any solution by searching in google.
Thank you.

Comment: see if setting `env.shell = '/bin/sh -l -c'` helps

Comment: `env.shell = '/bin/sh -l -c'` did not work, but `env.shell = '/bin/sh -c'` worked. Thank you very much!!